# Custom sort tsv-generated table in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Any idea how to create a custom-sortable table in D3.js with data from a TSV file? User can select which column(or columns) to sort by.

Here's my .js to create the table:

```
d3.tsv("data/score.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Name = d.Name;
        d.Id = d.Id;
        d.Score = d.Score;

    });

    function tabulate(data, columns) {
        var table = d3.select("#scoreTable").append("table"),
            thead = table.append("thead"),
            tbody = table.append("tbody");

        // append the header row
        thead.append("tr")
            .selectAll("th")
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
            .append("th")
            .text(function(column) {
                return column;
                });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("tr");

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function(column) {
                    return {
                        column: column, value: row[column]
                    };
                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .html(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });

        return table;
    }

    // render the table
    var peopleTable = tabulate(data, ["Name", "Id", "Final Score"]);

});
```

But I'm pretty much stuck from here.
I tried looking at:
[D3.js trying to implement sortable svg table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792791/d3-js-trying-to-implement-sortable-svg-table)

and:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3719724

But I'm not quite sure how to translate them to what I need. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track...

Just add the following code.

```
thead.append("tr")
     .selectAll("th")
     .data(columns)
     .enter()
     .append("th")
     .text(function(column) {
         return column;
     })
     .on('click', function (d) {
         rows.sort(function (a, b) {
         return a[d] - b[d];
      });
});
```

Added the `on('click', ...)` handler.

The parameter inside sort is a [comparator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
The argument `d` to the callback of `click` is the column name.

Comment: In what order should it sort if the values are equal?

Comment: Thanks! But the code doesn't seem work with non-number columns, like names.

Comment: Sorry, was a little confused. It was with text strings that it failed. Figured it out, though, by adding an if-else to treat strings with d3.ascending

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to pratyush's help, here's what worked. Added the on('click', ...) handler to the thead portion so it looks like this:

```
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) {
        return column;
    })
    .on('click', function (d) {
        rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (isNaN(a[d])) {
                return d3.ascending(a[d], b[d]);
            }
            else {
                return b[d] - a[d];
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks much, dude.