# reshuffling table columns with D3 or Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, d3.js

Hi fellow Javascripters,

I am using both Angular and D3 in my project (no jQuery, which I intend to keep this way). One thing that I want to support is to enable users to play with 'raw' tabular data. So, data from a CSV is loaded into my app and displayed in a plain old fashioned table (currently with Angulars ng-repeat). However, I now want to be able to animate that columns of the table get reshuffled. So, as a simple example, I would programmatically want to switch column 2 with column 4 and this transition must be D3-like. Furthermore, easily dragging whole columns to other positions should be possible.

Since I am not really experienced with working with jqLite inside Angular directives, my preference would go out to a solution based on D3. I can then see two possible solutions:

1. Render all of the data in a regular table using the D3 append functionality. Whenever column order changes, somehow reconstruct the table and create a smooth transition.
2. Simulate a table with div's and css (not looking forward to that though), to enable easy repositioning of data.

Since both solutions are far from trivial (I would say), I would really like to have some opinions. Do you see any other solutions for me? And if one of these two solutions seems right for you, how would you go about implementing them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792791/d3-js-trying-to-implement-sortable-svg-table)?

Comment: I have had a look, but it is targeted at transitioning table rows instead of columns. This was achieved by mimicking a table with divs, instead of using an actual table. So unfortunately, this does not quite solve my problem...

Comment: The same approach would be feasible if you organised your data in columns and not rows. Given that this approach isn't using HTML tables, this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: True, it would be feasible, but I would prefer to stick to actual HTML tables, since they offer a lot of convenience out of the box. For example, solving the problem of vertically aligning all the content in the different column divs will be a pain and I would prefer to not have to bother with that...

Comment: I don't see how you would get a smooth transition with HTML tables.

Comment: That is why I am asking, I thought maybe someone has experience with some neat tricks in this area.